# Microsoft SQL Server Extension Agent - Where is it enabled

Tags: sql-server, security

This is on a SQL Server 2016 SP1-CU3

Recently, these entries are appearing in our Security log table which traces any grants, revokes, user creation, etc.

[image]

And the host that is dropping these users from the SQLArcExtensionUserRole is the SQL Server itself.

I have searched Google and haven't found any relevant information.
Where is this activity coming from and how do I stop it?

Thank you,
Craig

Comment: There is an Azure Arc product for on-prem SQL Servers so I would guess that the SQLArcExtension is the agent that gets installed to run Azure Arc

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/azure-arc/overview?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Also, if it's _removing_ the member, then most likely it's being uninstalled.

Comment: @StephenMorris-Mo64, I neglected to mention that these revokes, alter roles are happening on a regular basis. Also, the login SQLArcExtensionUserRole doesn't exist and was never created.